# Domain Restriction in BabelNet

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to restrict the results of my BabelNet query to a specific (Babel)domain. To do that, I'm trying to find out a way to compare the synsets' domains with the domain I need (Geographical). However, I'm having trouble getting the right output, since although the 2 strings match, it still gives me the wrong output. I'm surely doing something wrong here, but I'm out of ideas.

After many trials, the following code was the one that gave me the nearest result to the desired output:

```
public class GeoRestrict {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "/path/to/file/testdata.txt";
        BabelNet bn = BabelNet.getInstance();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String word = null;
        
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
            BabelNetQuery query = new BabelNetQuery.Builder(word)
                    .build();
                    
            List<BabelSynset> wordSynset = bn.getSynsets(query);

            for (BabelSynset synset : wordSynset) {
                BabelSynsetID id = synset.getID();
                System.out.println("\n" + "Synset ID for " + word.toUpperCase() + " is: " + id);

                
                HashMap<Domain, Double> domains = synset.getDomains();
                Set<Domain> keys = domains.keySet();
                String keyString = domains.keySet().toString();            
                
                List<String> categories = synset.getDomains().keySet().stream()
                        .map(domain -> ((BabelDomain) domain).getDomainString())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
                
                for (String category : categories) {
                    if(keyString.equals(category)) {
                        System.out.println("The word " + word + " has the domain " + category);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nada! " + category);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         br.close();
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Synset ID for TURIN is: bn:00077665n
Nada! Geography and places
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own error. For the sake of completeness I'm posting it.

The BabelDomain needs to be declared and specified (before the while-loop), like this:

`BabelDomain domain = BabelDomain.GEOGRAPHY_AND_PLACES;`